# SimpleDateFormat throws ParseException

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Given the following String and formatter settings:

```
final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
final String date = "Mon Jan 25 16:33:06 CET 2016";
pojo.setTimestamp(formatter.parse(date));
```

I get an exception and do not understand what I should do to resolve it.

Comment: post the stack trace

Comment: Your format seems to be working fine.

Comment: Shouldn't be between date a "=". Could you please post your complete code?

Comment: @Kordi: Indeed, copy-paste mishappening.

Comment: Your code works fine: http://ideone.com/dknyr2 - unless you use a wrong locale: http://ideone.com/DGHZgj

Comment: @Ramanlfc: Stracktrace is just the regular "Unparseable date: "Mon Jan 25 16:33:06 CET 2016"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with the locale used in the `SimpleDateFormat`. By default, `SimpleDateFormat` takes the default locale of the system... so if you run this code in France, "Mon" won't be recognized as a day-of-week abbreviation, for example.

The simplest fix for this is just to call the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor which specifies a locale:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter =
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
```